# What are the rules regarding to numbers in RSA?

Tags: rsa, diffie-hellman, pki

I'd like to have a small sanity check first: As far as I understand, diffie-hellman is all about that fact that, given the generator ($g$), the modulo ($n$) and the remainder ($c$), it's hard to find the exponent a in:

$g^a \bmod n = c$

But the conditions for this are that n is a big prime number, and g is a root primitive. So my questions are:

1. Does $n$ **must** be prime? or it's just better for security?
2. Does $g$ **must** be root primitive mod $n$?

Ok now to RSA. As far as I understand, RSA stands on another notion, and that is that it's hard to find the message (m) given the cipher (c), modulo (n) and exponent (e) in:

$m^e \bmod n = c$

So my question is: Does the same restrictions regarding diffie-hellman apply to RSA? Seemingly that's not possible since:

1. you can't impose restrictions on the message itself
2. $n$ is a composite of two (or more) prime numbers.

Am I right here? Please correct me if not.

I suppose that my questions comes down to this: Do Diffie-Hellman and RSA rely on the same mechanism of modular arithmetic, or is it completely different?

Comment: DH relies on the Discrete Logarithm Problem (DLP), RSA on the RSA problem. Both use modular exponentiation. What's your question exactly? You need to study DH and RSA at least in some depth before trying to ask questions about it. Note that there are two "are"'s in your question title.

Comment: I removed the incorrect use of$\pmod n$ where $\bmod n$ was thought. $x\bmod n$ is the uniquely defined integer $y$ with $0\le y<n$ and $x-y$ a multiple of $n$. Whereas $x\pmod n$ is _not_ an integer, and $y\equiv x\pmod n$ only states that $y-x$ is a multiple of $n$, without specifying a range of $y$. The difference is important in both Diffie-Hellman and RSA.

Comment: Related question: [_Is Diffie-Hellman mathematically the same as RSA?_](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/797/555). Dupe, perhaps!

Comment: It's also generally misleading to think of the $m$ in RSA as a "message". It can be in some cases (OAEP-padding of a symmetric key for key exchange, though even then it's not the true "message" that eventually gets encrypted with that key) but often isn't (signatures, some random integer for RSA-KEM). Signatures are a lot more common as a use of RSA than RSA-OAEP for key exchange.

Comment: Also, we generally don't use a primitive root as a generator for DH, but a number which generates a large prime order subgroup.

Comment: n being composite makes it divisible into smaller more amenable problems if you know the factors. i.e given $c$ modulo $pq$, with prime $p$ and $q$, you can get $c$ modulo $p$ and $c$ modulo $q$, calculate them separately to get $m$ modulo $p$, $m$ modulo $q$, given $p$ and $q$ are small enough and combine them using Chinese remainder theorem to get $m$ mod $pq$. and  If you don't know the factors (as public information in an RSA group) you likely won't know the order of the group in question thus making its use in DH infeasible.